# Daily background task in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I'm building an app that fetches data from a third party server and syncs some of that data to my own server. The data for all users will be aggregated on my server and the results will be displayed in the app. The whole data sync (3rd party server -> App -> My server) should be done at least once a day. The app is only for a limited group of users and will be distributed with an enterprise account.

I'd prefer it to sync the data in the background, so the results on my server are always up to date and do not depend on the single users to open the app. I figured I'd use [setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:) with `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` so the sync would be handled in `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` in my AppDelegate. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to set a fixed interval for the background fetch. So I can't control when the sync is done, since it partly depends on the way the app is used when and how often the background fetch is executed.

Is there a way to modify the background fetch so I could guarantee the daily sync?
Or is there any other way to execute a background task on a daily basis with which I could accomplish the above?

The only solution I could come up with is a usability nightmare with daily local notifications to remind the users to open up the app, so that the background fetch can "learn" when to execute. I know this sounds bad, but I do have to present a solution to our customer :/

Comment: Sorry for not have good news...but, daily local notifications seems to me the only available option.

Comment: I'm afraid it seems that way. I did find another 'solution' which uses different background modes (audio & VOIP) to run a continuous task. But I'd rather call it a hack and only use it as last resort..